# Heroku/Node.js - Routing error of some kind causing Internal Server Errors

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I'm running a Node.js/Express/MongoHQ app on Heroku. It works perfectly locally. When I push to Heroku the root page '/' loads properly and DOES successfully access the MongoHQ DB. Every other route gives me an Internal Server Error and no identifiable error in the Heroku logs. Although if i go to /page/ I do get my app's 500 page to render properly (random...)

Is there anything you can think of that could be going wrong here? I thought it was a DB thing but now it seems like a routing thing. I'm happy to provide any code... I thought I'd paste in some of the log though it's super unhelpful to me anways. Any ideas MAJORYL appreciated.

Thanks.

Log (for basically any route other than '/')

```
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.94.69.43 - - [Fri, 07 Oct 2011 17:27:03 GMT] "GET /assets_js/lib/jquery.1.4.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "<MYSITE>/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET <MYSITE>/assets_js/lib/jquery.timeago.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET <MYSITE>/assets_js/lib/jquery.1.4.2.min.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET <MYSITE>/assets_js/lib/iscroll.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=0
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET <MYSITE>/assets_css/viewer.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=0
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET <MYSITE>/assets_js/utils.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=0
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.117.9.191 - - [Fri, 07 Oct 2011 17:27:03 GMT] "GET /assets_js/lib/iscroll.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "<MYSITE>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.117.11.66 - - [Fri, 07 Oct 2011 17:27:03 GMT] "GET /assets_css/viewer.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "<MYSITE>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET <MYSITE>/assets_js/mediacreate.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=0
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.94.74.117 - - [Fri, 07 Oct 2011 17:27:03 GMT] "GET /assets_js/mediacreate.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "<MYSITE>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET <MYSITE>/view_dashboard/activecard.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=0
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.84.93.33 - - [Fri, 07 Oct 2011 17:27:03 GMT] "GET /view_dashboard/activecard.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "<MYSITE>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET <MYSITE>/view_dashboard/drawon.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=0
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET <MYSITE>/assets_css/dashboard.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=0
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.64.155.131 - - [Fri, 07 Oct 2011 17:27:03 GMT] "GET /view_dashboard/dashboard.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "<MYSITE>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET <MYSITE>/view_presentation/cards/cards.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=0
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.84.95.29 - - [Fri, 07 Oct 2011 17:27:03 GMT] "GET /view_presentation/cards/cards.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "<MYSITE>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
2011-10-07T17:27:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.64.155.131 - - [Fri, 07 Oct 2011 17:27:03 GMT] "GET /view_presentation/cards/cards.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "<MYSITE>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
2011-10-07T17:27:05+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.64.147.7 - - [Fri, 07 Oct 2011 17:27:05 GMT] "GET /assets_img/graph.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 - "<MYSITE>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
2011-10-07T17:27:05+00:00 heroku[router]: <MYSITE>/assets_img/graph.gif dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
2011-10-07T17:27:05+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.84.95.29 - - [Fri, 07 Oct 2011 17:27:05 GMT] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 1682 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
2011-10-07T17:27:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET <MYSITE>/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=1682
```

Comment: It looks like you have your static files misconfigured.  Can you post that part of your express configuration? Should look like `app.use(express['static'](__dirname+'/public', {maxAge: 86400000}));` if you're using the boilerplate template.

Comment: ok cool, i hope you're onto something here.  this is my current static dir `  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` and then i have 5 folders within that "assets_css, assets_js etc...". The only reason I'm not totally convinced that could be it is when I go to '/' it does seem to pull in all those files properly.

Comment: The problem seems to be in your routes definition or server.js definition (how to handle favicon.ico).
Can you publish those?

Comment: A peek at your app.js file would be helpful.  Also, just to be sure, do you have all of your module dependencies added to your package.json file?

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities I can think of:

- Your version of node.js might not be the exact same as heroku's. Run `node --version` to find yours and then add something like this to package.json to make heroku use the same version: `"engines": { "node": "0.6.14"}`
- You have a different version of some dependency locally than what's specified in your package.json. Run `npm ls` to see what you have locally and pay attention to heroku's logs when you push to see what versions it downloads.
- You have some important file locally that isn't checked in: `git status` Also check your `.gitignore` and `.slugignore` files if you have them.
- It's possible it's an OS thing, I'm not sure which flavor but I'm pretty sure heroku runs Linux. `require('os').type()` and `require('os').release()` can give you a little bit of info here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I deployed to Heroku. Turned out the name of my files broke the code on live but not locally.

For example I had a view called createSession.hbs. In my route (createSession.js) I was doing

`res.render('createsession', {...});`

On local the capital 'S' didn't matter but when deployed I was getting the Internal Server Error.

My local OS was Windows and I deployed on Heroku (Ubuntu server).

Stupid and annoying error as it worked locally but hope it helps someone.